# Is it possible to install sketch and zeplin in Ubuntu?

Tags: application-development, tools

Good to all I want to install sketch and zeplin in my Ubuntu 18.04 but I can not find the way to do it.

I've searched on Google, and only versions for Mac and Windows appear.
Is there a way to install these tools in Ubuntu?

Are there similar tools for designing applications in Ubuntu?

Thank you.

Comment: I recommend Avocode, many more features and easier to use

Answer (score 2):

Sketch itself is MacOS only - Sketch has no plans to support Windows or Linux - it heavily leverages a lot of the native MacOS frameworks and native technologies.

However, there is a non-Sketch, Sketch-like product called Lunacy that lets you read and edit Sketch files on Windows. You might get it working under Ubuntu with Wine.

Zeplin doesn't have a Linux version (and the Windows version doesn't export from Sketch on Windows because, well, there isn't Sketch for Windows! It exports from Photoshop etc)  - but there is Zeplin's webapp that can be run from any platform.

Answer (score 0):

To install zeplin:
[enter link description here](https://snapcraft.io/install/zeplin-lukewh/ubuntu)

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. While posting a link to the Snap store is certainly appreciated, could you expand on your answer, saying what the link is for? This way, if the URL changes in the future, people can use a little Google-fu to work out an updated solution 